# 389 directory server entries password(userpassword) location

Tags: directory, ldap, store

I have one 'very' big question, so if anyone can help me will be nice. And the question is :
Does anyone know where 389 directory server stores passwords of created entries (data from userpassword attribute)?
This is place where i chacked but i don't find any hashed password:
**/var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-serverName/db/userRoot** and there is data for attributes like sn,cn,mail etc, but i can't find where is data from attribute userpassword. When i make export of database i get SSHA line about password in exported ldif file, but what i want is place where are they stored..

And yes i already search on google but i can't find what i need.

Comment: You have already found where they are stored. As a one-way SSHA hash.

What is your intent?

-jim

Comment: I'm just curious where they 'live':], there is no file named userpassword.db4 like files for sn,cn,mail(mail.db4, sn.db4) etc..

Answer (score 0):

It seems all attributes are in userRoot/id2entry.db. You can dump them with `dbscan -f id2entry.db`:
https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/design/database-architecture.html